# Intensity of whipping in Westminster style parliaments with party systems

Tags: parliament

Which Westminster style parliaments with party systems have the most intense whipping? Which have the least?

Comment: This seems likely to change over time.  Whipping (politician to politician lobbying) can change vote to vote, much less from one prime minister to another.  So the UK is likely to see a lot of it for a while with its minority government.  Other parliaments might replace them after the next election.  No idea who would be the recent leader.